# to see which case I'm in in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I always mis-press the **caps lock** key when I typing. So there are lots of time that I don't know which case I actually in. I always have go into insert mode to test, which is painful. So are there any method to tell vim to show the case I'm in all the time?
thanks.

By the way, I using powerlines plugin, which may disable some feature of the original vim. If it does, let me know please.

Comment: Why don't you look at the light on your keyboard?

Comment: I cannot tell from my keyboard.

Comment: There is an entire exchange specifically for vi/vim http://vi.stackexchange.com and you might get a better answer there.

Answer (score 2):

If you press Caps Lock inadvertently, you should disable it or remap it.

According to [this vim thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Caps-Lock-indication-td4556863.html), there is not a platform-independent way to accomplish what you are asking for in vim.